# How do I install the opus audio encoder?

Tags: sound, encoding, ogg-opus

I would like to try out the [opus audio encoder](http://www.octasic.com/en/tech/opus_audio_codec.php), but can't find it in the repositories.  Can anyone here help me get it installed on my computer?  I have some wav files which I would like to convert to the opus audio format.

However, I have found [this link](http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/core/quantal/universe/base/opus-tools), but each time I click on the appropriate deb download, the package manager opens, but displays an error message saying that there are dependency issues (lib0gg0).

Comment: My answer [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/211054/how-to-convert-a-sound-file-to-opus/239356#239356) might help if you are on 12.04.

Answer (score 10):

The [opus audio codecs](http://packages.ubuntu.com/quantal/opus-tools) are installed with the following packages:

- **libogg0** (>= 1.3.0)
- **libopus0**
- **opus-tools**

All these packages are already built ready to be available for Ubuntu 12.10 alpha and can be downloaded from the mirrors.

However be warned: if you downloaded these not yet fully tested packages and installed them manually in an earlier Ubuntu release you may break your sound system in case there are incompatibilites. This may especially be true for the Ogg library as the upgraded version replaces the previous installed older version.

Answer (score 4):

This is an older question but times have indeed changes and with Trusty Tahr now you have a few easier choices:

1. Install the `opus-tools` package:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install opus-tools
   ```

   and then create opus files from the commandline:

   ```
   opusenc --bitrate 128 input.wav output.opus
   ```
2. Install the `libav-tools` package:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install libav-tools
   ```

   and then create your opus files from the commandline:

   ```
   avconv -i input.wav -c:a libopus -b:a 128k output.opus
   ```

Newer versions of Ubuntu can now use FFmpeg rather than avconv, but still using the external libopus library...