# Video Conversion using libav with libopus

Tags: 12.10, ffmpeg, conversion, libav

i need to convert my video files with VP8 / Opus in Matroska(mkv) container using `avconv` in terminal
Can anyone give example usage of it?

Comment: Hi, welcome to AskUbuntu. Right now it is not really clear what your question is. Please describe what your trying to do, what maybe failed or what you want to do exactly. This help us to understand your question better and to give you a nice answer. ;-)

Comment: is the avconv/ffmeg a hard restriction? Or are other applications also allowed

Comment: i want try it with 'libopus'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Actually you can't because the Matroska container doesn't support the Opus audio codec yet.**

source: [Codec Specs | Matroska](http://matroska.org/technical/specs/codecid/index.html)

---

Apart from that the most simple way to transcode a video with VP8 is to use [transmageddon [image: Install transmageddon]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/transmageddon)

Opus support for transmageddon was added in November 2012 (just after 0.25 was released), so you'll have to wait for 0.26. (source: [Gnome Transmageddon Repository](http://git.gnome.org/browse/transmageddon/log/))

Alternatively you can compile ffmpeg from source (otherwise you won't have VP8 or Opus) following the instructions on the [ffmeg site](https://ffmpeg.org/trac/ffmpeg/wiki/UbuntuCompilationGuide).

Comment: is there any other container supporting opus

Comment: Not that I know of, but support for Matroska is in progress, once it is in Matroska it will also be supported in Webm. source: https://code.google.com/p/webm/issues/detail?id=453

Comment: I recently compiled the opus codec and compiled ffmpeg with opus support, as I discussed [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/211054/how-to-convert-a-sound-file-to-opus/239356#239356).

Comment: The Ogg container handles Opus perfectly well (and has since Opus came out).