# Please give me an FFMPEG tutorial that works on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: ffmpeg

`ffmpeg` does not compile. 
Every time there is an error no matter what I do. 
I installed clean 12.04, followed the tutorial on ffmpeg website, but it is still not working.

If its not `libfdk-aac` error, it's `libx246` error.

Can someone please help?

I just tried to follow another tutorial and it complaints about `libfdk-aac`. I have it installed, multiverse reps are done too, it's all there. 
If I remove `--enable-libfdk-aac` from `ffmpeg ./configure`, then it complaints about `libx264`. 
I installed `libx264-dev` and it works but eventually comes with failed error mentioning x264:

```
libavcodec/libx264.c:552: error: undefined reference to 'x264_encoder_open_130' collect2: ld returned 1 exit status make: *** [ffmpeg_g] Error 1
```

Comment: Try my answer [for this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/211054/how-to-convert-a-sound-file-to-opus/239356#239356), where I give some tips on compiling `ffmpeg` while referring to the official guide. I have compiled it several times on 12.04. You must remove any existing related packages and install the build dependencies (as noted on the guide), then compile the various components in order (i.e. x264, etc before `ffmpeg`, which should be last of all).

Comment: Hi. I really appreciate your effort to reply to my question. Unfortunately i have yet again followed exactly what you said and the error is still the same when i try to ./configure ffmpeg ERROR: libfdk_aac not found. I have libfsk_aac installed, multiverse repos are enabled too. What am i doing wrong? This is a fresh Server 12.04 install.

Comment: I'm not sure really: the build dependencies are slightly different for server, did you install those and not the desktop ones? I'll do a fresh compile and see if I get any errors.

Comment: I have installed a fresh 12.04 this morning and this time before i did anything, i followed the tutorial and it worked! So something that i have done before must have created a problem. Anyway, now I have another problem with using FFMPEG through Clip-Bucket script, but its not relevant for this thread. I do appreciate your effort on this, thank you!

Comment: I'll put an answer so that the question can be seen as solved. If you want, you can ask another question with the other issue you have discovered.

Comment: The `undefined reference` error most likely indicates that you have two versions of `x264.h` installed (the bad one is probably from libx264-dev) resulting in broken builds.

Answer (score 2):

We solved the problems after various discussions in the comments where I linked to my [detailed guide](https://askubuntu.com/questions/211054/how-to-convert-a-sound-file-to-opus/239356#239356), which also references the [official ffmpeg guide](http://ffmpeg.org/trac/ffmpeg/wiki/UbuntuCompilationGuide).

[Andrej's](https://askubuntu.com/users/138451/andrej) system was Ubuntu 12.04 server.

It is only possible to list some general points below, as there was no one single issue that was the problem in the failed compilation attempts:

- Firstly, it is necessary to remove any existing packages  with

  ```
  sudo apt-get remove ffmpeg x264 libav-tools libvpx-dev libx264-dev
  ```

  so that possible conflicts are avoided when trying to compile `ffmpeg` and its libraries later.
- In the official [ffmpeg guide](http://ffmpeg.org/trac/ffmpeg/wiki/UbuntuCompilationGuide)  the dependencies are slightly different for desktop and server, and there are also several notes throughout the guide that should be followed if installing on a server. The sets of build dependencies for desktop and server are listed in the [official guide](http://ffmpeg.org/trac/ffmpeg/wiki/UbuntuCompilationGuide).
- One thing [Andrej](https://askubuntu.com/users/138451/andrej) mentioned was that he had got dependencies such as `libx264-dev`, but actually that is one of the things that should be **removed** (as in the first command above). If you want x264 support or aac support, etc, you must compile `x264`, `fdk-aac`, `libvpx` and `opus` **before** you build `ffmpeg`. Compiling `ffmpeg` should be the last thing done; you should not download the build dependencies and then begin compiling `ffmpeg` as you need to compile several libraries yourself if you want the various support for certain audio/video types.
- If it is proving problematic to compile certain libraries or build `ffmpeg` with support for them, you should be able to edit the `ffmpeg` `./configure` line in [the guide](http://ffmpeg.org/trac/ffmpeg/wiki/UbuntuCompilationGuide); e.g. to remove an `--enable-libxxx` line. Conversely, for `opus` support, you need to add `--enable-libopus`. I was about to suggest further tweaking the `./configure` line, when [Andrej](https://askubuntu.com/users/138451/andrej) solved his problem, but it is useful to remember this for future builds if problems occur.
- For more details on compiling `ffmpeg` and possible problems that can arise, see [my detailed answer for this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/211054/how-to-convert-a-sound-file-to-opus/239356#239356).