# OPus Audio codec install on Lubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, lubuntu, ogg-opus

Anyone please share info. on how I can port opus audio codec on a system running Lubuntu 14.04
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean how to install this:
https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/opus

Then, the solution would be:

```
sudo apt-get install libopus0
```

If you mean something else, try rephrasing your answer.

Comment: Would installing this give the complete opus codec package or is there anything else I would need to install?

Comment: try installing opus-tools too, as indicated in the question mentioned by Paulius. I still have not understood exactly what you want to do. It might be that you want to install the dev packages too (libopus-dev)

Comment: I have some .wav files that i want to convert to opus format.

Comment: You will need opus-tools and then follow the instructions here https://askubuntu.com/questions/211054/how-to-convert-a-sound-file-to-opus