# Convert a .MP4 to Opus Via Command Line?

Tags: command-line, video, files, convert

I'm looking for a command line method to convert `.mp4`'s to `.opus` files. I've read ([How to convert a sound file to Opus](https://askubuntu.com/questions/211054/how-to-convert-a-sound-file-to-opus)), but most (If not all) of the answers were unable to do so in a command line format that actually runs on my system. NOTE: I've made sure that I installed all the required libraries

The post is rather dated, and the commands don't work. Is there an easy command line method to convert a local `.mp4` to `.opus`? I would prefer a single command instead of say 2 or 3, but that would be ok too.

Command 0:

> `opusenc --bitrate 510 --max-delay 10 "music.mp3" "music.opus"
>
>   Error parsing input file: music.mp3`

Using ffmpeg:

> `ffmpeg "Ace Combat 6 OST - The Liberation Of Gracemeria.mp4" "Ace Combat 6 OST - The Liberation Of Gracemeria.opus" 
>   ffmpeg version 3.3.4-2 Copyright (c) 2000-2017 the FFmpeg developers
>    built with gcc 7 (Ubuntu 7.2.0-8ubuntu2)
>     configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=2 --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librubberband --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libopencv --enable-libx264 --enable-shared
>     WARNING: library configuration mismatch
>     avcodec     configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=2 --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librubberband --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libopencv --enable-libx264 --enable-shared --enable-version3 --disable-doc --disable-programs --enable-libopencore_amrnb --enable-libopencore_amrwb --enable-libtesseract --enable-libvo_amrwbenc --enable-netcdf
>     libavutil      55. 58.100 / 55. 58.100
>     libavcodec     57. 89.100 / 57. 89.100
>     libavformat    57. 71.100 / 57. 71.100
>     libavdevice    57.  6.100 / 57.  6.100
>     libavfilter     6. 82.100 /  6. 82.100
>     libavresample   3.  5.  0 /  3.  5.  0
>     libswscale      4.  6.100 /  4.  6.100
>     libswresample   2.  7.100 /  2.  7.100
>     libpostproc    54.  5.100 / 54.  5.100`

However at the end in red is: `Output #0, mp4, to 'Ace Combat 6 OST - The Liberation Of Gracemeria.mp4':
Output file #0 does not contain any stream` And no file appears in the folder.

Comment: @dsstorefile That would require me to post an output for every command there. That would certainly take a while, but I suppose it is do-able

Comment: @SarahSzabo You mean mp4 or mp3? Both are in your question, mind you neither are handled directly by opusenc...

Comment: @dsstorefile I did that last night, but I couldn't post about it because I was beyond tired and it was 4 hours after when I usually go to sleep. That and I had a brutal day of schoolwork.

Comment: @dsstorefile Nice, I'm unfamiliar with `ffmpeg` I got it using the new syntax with the -b 320k option.